# Maven clean install / jar:jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

When I try to run `mvn clean install -U` or `mvn jar:jar`

it fails with:

```
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.15/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.1/plexus-archiver-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.2/plexus-io-2.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/commons-lang-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
```

The projet is built fine with: `mvn compiler:compile`.

All jar files exist.

I don't understand how is it possible to fail when it just create a simple jar file...

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: By the way, mvn package does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the answer, prepare yourself:

```
rd /Q /S C:\Users\XXX\.m2\repository
mvn clean install -U
mvn package
```

It works without any issue...
Still don't understand why the jar was corrupted as it was previously downloaded by maven...

Comment: First using configuration to check the checksum policy https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/ second just use `mvn clean install` only and supplemental `mvn package` duplicates a lot...